# Self-Study in Discrete Mathematics: Linear Recurrence Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Through self-study of mathematics, I accidentally stumbled into an area called Linear Recurrence Relations. After poking around in a few different websites I think I'm starting to grasp the idea. I'm just looking to clarify something I read to see if I'm understanding something correctly.
On one of the of the websites I was looking at it, it gave the following example:

$x_1=3, x_n=3x_{n-1}$

$x_2=3x_1=9$

$x_3=3x_2=27$

$x_4=3x_3=81$

Having "solved" the equation for multiple instances, it is noticed that the answers are powers of 3. Thereby making the formula $x_n=3^n$.

I have a few questions.

1. Is it valid to re-write the starting formula as $x_{n+1}=3x_n$ or does this fundamentally change something with the base formula?
2. Is it necessary to solve for several iterations of the base equation to derive the formula or is there a method to have inferred the $x_n=3^n$ from the original formula?
3. Are the solvable iterations necessary for proof?

I will probably have more questions. As this area of mathematics is new to me, and has been self-study. Also, I apologize for any improper use of LaTeX. I'm just now learning of it and how to write with it. So if something doesn't look right, it's probably due to my inexperience with it.

Comment: (1) Either is fine.
(2) There is such a method!  We can find a formula for any sequence given by a recurrence relation.  The solutions always look like linear combinations of exponentials $a^n$; however the constants $a$ may not have convenient forms.  I'd say keep studying and you will likely find out why this is the case.
(3) I'm not clear on what this question means. If you're asking whether you have to generate a lot of elements in the sequence before finding the formula, the answer is no, as above; there are algebraic ways to find it directly from the recurrence and initial conditions.

Comment: There's a sort-of a story behind the third question, that explains how I found myself here. I was playing around with some mathematical functions and through some intuition, I found a pattern. I was then able to derive a functional formula to describe the pattern. But, it was self-referential. Meaning that it required a previous answer to obtain the next answer. I worked out several of these, made a couple predictions, and watched them come true. I asked over on Reddit r/Math if there was a way to derive a more reasonable formula. Was told that its a Non-Homogenous, Linear, recurrence relation

Comment: So I'm doing what I can to self-study the field. While the helpful users over on Reddit did provide a working formula derived from the one I found in the pattern. I'm trying to learn how they made that formula. I asked a Professor at the online college I'm attending and he literally said, go to this website, (here), to ask all of my questions.

So I apologize. I quite literally just got pawned off from my university to all of you.

Comment: No need to apologize. Feel free to ask your question - you should be a bit more specific on the details though.

Comment: In the example above. If I were to write a proof for the example. Would I need to predict a future number using the algebraic equation then, using the difference equation, work up to my prediction to prove the accuracy of the algebraic equation?

Comment: Which do you consider the algebraic equation vs. the 'difference' equation?  It sounds as if you might be asking if you can derive the formula $x_n = 3^{n-1}$ without having to generate entries in the sequence, and the answer to that is yes.  You can use the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Roots_of_the_characteristic_polynomial); in this the polynomial for $a_n = 3a_{n-1}$ is $p(x) = x-3$ and its one root is $x=3$, so the formula must be of the form $x_n = k3^{n}$ and you need only solve for $k$ using the initial condition $x_1 = 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither $x_n=3x_{n-1}$ nor $ x_{n+1}=3x_n$ is a rigorous sentence, as neither of them specifies the values of $n$ for which it holds. The (presumed) intent of the example is $$(i)....\quad x_1=3\land \forall n\in \Bbb N\, (n\ge 2\implies x_n=3x_{n-1}\,).$$ This is equivalent to $$(ii)....\quad x_1=3\land \forall m\in \Bbb N\,  (x_{m+1}=3x_m).$$ The only reason $(i)$ looks more complicated than $(ii)$ is that we don't have a standard 1-letter symbol for $\{n\in\Bbb N:n\ge 2\}.$

We can prove $\forall n\in\Bbb N\,(x_n=3^n)$ by induction on $n$ without explicitly calculating $x_n$ for any $n>1.$

In more complicated examples it is often useful to compute several iterations in order to obtain a plausible conjecture for a formula, but a proof is still required.

Comment: Still learning. But I spent the weekend watching YT videos as I did not understand any of those symbols. Here's what I got from those video lectures.

3 ?Conjunction? for all sub-elements 'n' of the set of all natural numbers. such that as long as 'n' is greater than or equal to 2, implies that $x_n = 3x_{n-1}$ is true.

not sure how the conjunction part works just yet.

Comment: (i) says that $x_1=3$ $and$ ("$\land$") that if $n$ is any natural number ("$\forall n\in \Bbb N$") with $n\ge 2$ then $x_n=3x_{n-1}.$